# Casting negative numbers

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to interpret hex bytes and consolidate them into useful information.

```
void processData(){
  signed char data;
  unsigned long a;//holds four bytes
  unsigned long b;
  unsigned int c;//holds two bytes
  unsigned char d;//holds one byte

  a=readA();//readA,readB,readC,readD return one unsigned byte;
  b=readB();
  c=readC();
  d=readD();

  data=(signed char) ((0xffffffff-((a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)))/1000);

}
```

The scenario is that the whole package received contains a four-byte information, for example a value of 0xAABBCCDD. readA() will return the highest byte in the package i.e. 0xAA. readD() will return 0xDD. So I need to shift them before using "|" to put them together: `(a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)`

So my question is, for right hand side of this sentence

`data=(signed char) ((0xffffffff-((a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)))/1000);`

why does it not return a char while I cast the result to a signed char? When I print it out everything is wrong. However, if I set `data` as signed long, everything is correct. I guess it's because signed char was not big enough to hold all information and caused overflows.

Correct me if I am wrong, variables in `((a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)))` will all be implicitly cast to unsigned long and so is the result of this expression. `((a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)))/1000` will also return a unsigned long number. However the result will be significantly smaller since it's divided by 1000.

The four-byte information ranges from 0xFFFF5037 to 0xFFFFFFFF, which is also the range of the result of this expression `((a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)))`.

So the right hand side of the expression should be between 0 to 45 after the division is done. But when I print the result it's all jumping around.

Comment: I suspect that the cast is somehow telling the compiler "no need to maintain precision on this calculation"; did you try doing this in two lines? First line performs bit manipulation, second line casts to `(signed char)`?

Comment: yes. I even tried to shift a,b,d and d in separate lines.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are always `0xFF`, why include them? Try `(0xFFFF - ((c<<8)|d))/1000`

Comment: Why use `|` rather than `+`?

Comment: if your information has a width of 45000 then why dont you just use an unsigned short(assuming 2 bytes) and just manipulate `C` and `D` only? the MSB 16 bits are anyways redundant for the information you get.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the results of intermediate steps in your calculations?  I wouldn't expect your code to produce the results you're expecting.

Comment: how will it be -45 to 0 in RHS? it will be 0 to 45 right?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `sizeof (unsigned long)` could be 1, depending on `CHAR_BIT`... and that a byte in C contains `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Answer (score 2):

**6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged. 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is
>   converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the
>   maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value
>   is in the range of the new type. 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed
>   and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
>   implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

The code you've given us might behave in different ways depending on the choices made by the implementations we use. It's not unreasonable to see an implementation raising an implementastion-defined signal corresponding to an exceptional condition, such as SIGSEGV. If the implementation decides that the default action is to ignore that signal, then you lay in the realm of undefined behaviour for that implementation.

Do the calculation in the longer types, then convert the longer value to a smaller value by reducing it modulo to the correct width, and adding to SCHAR_MIN to produce the negative values if necessary. (*read comments*)

```
void processData(){
    signed char data;
    unsigned long a; // holds sizeof (unsigned long) bytes*
    unsigned long b;
    unsigned int c;  // holds sizeof (int) bytes*
    unsigned char d; // holds one byte
                     // Footnote: int and unsigned long might have padding bits
                     // --------- Attempting to modify those padding bits can 
                     //           result in undefined behavior...

    a = (readA() << 24) + (readB() << 16) + (readC() << 8) + d;
    a /= 1000;

    a %= UCHAR_MAX;
    if (a <= SCHAR_MAX) {
        // the value will fit safely into data as per point 1 of 6.3.1.3
        data = a;
    }
    else if (a >= (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN) {
        // Since converting negative values to positive values will result 
        // in values greater than or equal to (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN, 
        // by reducing a modulo
        // (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN we work out how many to add to SCHAR_MIN.
        data = SCHAR_MIN + (a % (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN);
    }
    else {
        // The value is out of range. Perhaps it corresponds to a negative zero?
        data = 0;
    }
}
```

The last condition-chain can be shortened to:

```
data = a <= SCHAR_MAX                 ? a
     : a >= (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN? SCHAR_MIN +(a % (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN)
     : 0;
```

Comment: if I set SCHAR_MIN to -128 will (unsigned char) SCHAR_MIN be zero?

Comment: @Timtianyang It isn't your job to set `SCHAR_MIN`. That's the job of the people who wrote your C compiler/standard library/headers. `SCHAR_MIN` is defined in `#include <limits.h>`. Don't change it. Just use it.

Comment: Sorry, I am actually using a standard ANSI C compiler for microcontrollers (mikroC compiler). I don't know if what you said cam apply to it or not. The purpose of not setting the variable "data" as long type is because shifting, assigning values will waste some instruction cycles for the chip. I would prefer data to be a smaller type. I am now really confused by your code now. Can I cast ((readA() << 24) + (readB() << 16) + (readC() << 8) + d) into unsigned char first to chop off some unused bits and then use 2's compliment to make it negative and store it in data?

Comment: I acutally missed a point in my original question. I meant to assign value ((a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|(d)-0xffffffff))/1000 to "data".

Comment: @Timtianyang The section I quoted from the standard is relevant to any C compiler. In my code, data is the same type as yours. If you're concerned about assignments, then consider that you don't need to assign readA(), readB(), readC() and readD() to different variables. Have you considered that your compiler might be an optimising compiler? Why restrict yourself to systems that only use twos complement representation? Your compiler might be smart enough to realise that my if-else if-else chain produces the same result as your restrictive twos complement translation, and produce the same code.

Comment: another question, in this statement a = (readA() << 24) + (readB() << 16) + (readC() << 8) + d; it seems like you are left-shifting unsigned bytes to a higer position they don't meant to be, which will cause information loss. I got 0 from (readA() << 24) + (readB() << 16).

Answer (score 1):

The result of this will be a negative 32-bit number that will not fit in a signed char. Your code doesn't make any sense, therefore you get an output which doesn't make sense either.

In practice, all systems in the real world are two's complement systems and will behave like this:

`(signed char)0xAABBCCDD` will try to store DD into a signed char variable, regardless of whether the whole 32 bit value was signed or not. The original sign bit is lost. Furthermore, the MSB in the two's complement number 0xDD will get treated as the sign bit. Thus if you try to print the signed char containing 0xDD you will get a negative number.

Had it been `(signed char)0xAABBCC0D` then you would get 0D and no sign bit set, because the MSB of 0D is not set.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the sigh bit and I totally ignored it. But why is the number negative? The range of 0xAABBCCDD is from 0xFFFF5037 to 0xFFFFFFFF. If I subtract a smaller number from a larger number isn't the result positive? If the result is positive I can safely assign it to a signed char variable right?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of data to `long` and print it out with something like `printf("%lx", data)`. That will give you a better clue.

Comment: `%lx` corresponds to an `unsigned long` argument. `data` will be promoted to an `int`. Passing an `int` when printf expects an `unsigned long` is undefined behaviour.